# EasyMock - HttpSession Setting session - method pass via request

Tags: junit, easymock, httpsession

I'm wondering on a request pass to a method and pulling the HttpSession?

Following from JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testSessionPass(){
    HttpServletRequest request = createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpSession session = createMock(HttpSession.class);
    expect(session.getAttribute("testAttribute")).andReturn("testValue").anyTimes();
    replay(request);
    replay(session);

    CAction cAction = new CAction();
    cAction.test(request);


}
```

In the CAction:

```
 public void test (HttpServletRequest request){
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if(session.getAttribute("testAttribute")!=null){
             System.out.println((String)session.getAttribute("testAttribute"));
        }
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

Why am I loosing the session from the passed request value at line HttpSession session = request.getSession();  ??

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: When I pass in the request parameter I'm loosing the session value for testAttribute.  It is actually dieing on the HttpSession session = request.getSession(); line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't mocking the call to `getSession()`

Add this line before your calls to `replay()`

```
expect(request.getSession()).andReturn(session);
```